sshfs and autofs : what is the correct syntax for auto.sshfs
I have a NAS. I would like to have a remote directory. I am having a problem of setting up a sshfs share using auto.fs.
I have playing around with autofs and sshfs. I can get the NFS shares to work correctly, but when it comes to sshfs. There is a problem! When I manually configure sshfs, it works just fine. Command below works great on a temp basis.
    sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions  admin@10.10.10.254:/share/PublicData/000 /home/aaa/Pictures/00/

The above code works great mounts and works until reboot or some other network outage.
https://www.tjansson.dk/2008/01/autofs-and-sshfs-the-perfect-couple/
I have been using the above link as a guide among a few others
Here is my auto.master line:
    /home/aaa/Pictures/00 /etc/autofs.sshfs uid=1000,gid=1000,--ghost,--timeout=60

I have been doing some research and have a more verbose line that I have merged from different sources. Not entirely, sure they are in the correct order either. Example: the uid and gid are in both the master and sshfs file. I will enclose at the end. Here is the contents of the most direct one I can find : auto.sshfs:
    00 -fstype=fuse,rw,auto,allow_other,default_permissions \:sshfs\#admin@10.10.10.10\:/share/PublicData/000/\:

Also tried this and a few different varations.
    00 -fstype=fuse,rw,auto,allow_other,default_permissions :sshfs\#admin@10.10.10.10\:/share/PublicData/000/\:

I tried many different combinations. This is the simplest and most straight forward.
I was trying to have a remote file share. I was looking at the following line:
    000 -fstype=fuse,rw,delay_connect,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMAX=3,imap=user,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,noatime,_netdev,workaround=rename,IdentityFile=/home/aaa/.ssh/id_rsa :sshfs\#admin@10.10.10.10:/share/PublicData/000

I would appreciate any help! It appears to be straight forward. I must be missing something. If you help, with the first item would be good. The second would be great!!!
Thanks for listening.
